# How do I downgrade node.js?

Tags: node.js, linux, discord.js

So when I did all of my installations and such, I downloaded node.js 15.something instead of 14.15.1 LTS. How would I go about downgrading this, preferably with the `n` or `nvm` commands. I have tried doing `n 14.15.1`, `n lts`, and `nvm use 14.15.1`, however none of them have worked

Comment: You could try `n prune` to remove any cached versions and `n uninstall` then reinstall the version you want

Comment: that didn't work, no. It still says 15.5.1. Could it possibly have to do with the fact that, when I originally got node.js, I got it with nvm?

Answer (score 1):

Check which versions you have installed using the command `nvm ls`

If you don't have the version you'd like to downgrade to, you need to install the version you want first and then you can use it.

`nvm install 14.15.1`

`nvm use 14.15.1`